# A button's hover effect is affecting another button's hover effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a weird thing happening here. When I hover over a button, it disappears and another button right above it takes its effect meaning its color changes when actually the button that is hovered over should change its color.

Here's what creates the buttons:

```
createDiv () {

        //  div
       const div = document.createElement('div')
       document.body.appendChild(div)
       div.className = "account-div";
       div.id = "account-div"

       
        // input for Name
       const input = document.createElement('input')
       input.className = "account-input"
       div.appendChild(input)
       input.value = this.state.displayName;
       input.addEventListener('change', this.changeName)
        // label
       const label = document.createElement('label')
       label.className = 'account-label'
       input.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', label)
       label.textContent = "Name:";
        // update button
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.className = 'account-button';
        input.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', button)
        button.textContent = "Update"
        button.addEventListener('click', this.updateName)


        // input for Email
       const input2 = document.createElement('input')
       input2.className = "account-input2"
       div.appendChild(input2)
       input2.value = this.state.email;
       input2.addEventListener('change', this.changeEmail)
        // label
       const label2 = document.createElement('label')
       label2.className = 'account-label2'
       input2.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', label2)
       label2.textContent = "Email:";
        // update button
        const update = document.createElement('button');
        update.className = 'update-button';
        update.id = "update-button-id"
        input2.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', update)
        update.textContent = "Update"
        update.addEventListener('click', this.updateEmail)
     }
```

This is the CSS:

```
.account-input {
    
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: -10px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 30px; 
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 70%;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: border-color 0.2s;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  
  .account-input::placeholder {
    color: lightgray;
  }
  
  .account-input:focus {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }

  .account-label {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      left: 40px;
  }

  .account-button {
      position: absolute;
      left: 150px;
      top: 110px;

      background: none!important;
      border: none;
      padding: 0!important;
      color: lightblue;
      
  }

  .account-button:hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 110px;

    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: lightgrey;
    
}

.account-button:active {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 110px;

    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;

    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: burlywood;

    
    
}




.account-input2 {
    
    position: relative;
    left: 40px;
    top: 30px;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 30px; 
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 70%;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: border-color 0.2s;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }
  
  .account-input2::placeholder {
    color: lightgray;
  }
  
  .account-input2:focus {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #11998e, #38ef7d);
    border-image-slice: 1;
  }

  .account-label2 {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 140px;
      left: 40px;
  }

  #update-button-id {
      position: absolute;
      left: 150px;
      top: 210px;

      background: none;
      border: none;
      padding: 0;
      color: lightblue;
      
  }

  #update-button-id:hover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 110px;

    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: green;
    
}

#update-button-id:active {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 110px;

    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;

    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    color: green;
      
    
}
```

This is how it looks. The code runs when Account is pressed:

[image]

This is what happens when the second button (update) is hovered over. Basically, it disappears and the first update button takes its CSS:

[image]

I tried to target the buttons with className and IDs in CSS but both yield the same result.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Hey – is this supposed to be a ReactJs project? I see `this.state` somewhere in there?

Comment: Yes, it is. Why? Do you see an issue?

Comment: Yes yes, one of the main ideas behind React is that you almost never have to write code like this. Can you give me a description of the whole feature? I can give you an idea of how to structure it pragmatically in a way that you don't run into issues?

Comment: I created this code in an attempt to create less hidden elements so that the DOM is not so big when it is loaded. I could be more wrong. More specifically, the code works when Account is pressed in the settings. Instead of hiding and showing Account's div with CSS which would make it part of the html, I decided to use JS to accomplish this. Please see the images I uploaded in my question to get an idea. You can see how the second button disappears when it is hovered over and instead the button above it turns green when the second one should do it.

Comment: I agree with @DamilareOlusakin — code like this should generally be avoided in React unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Beyond knowing what you're doing, I'm not sure you should be doing this unless you absolutely need to directly mutate or inject elements into the DOM, maybe you're dealing with an integrated library that isn't very React specific. I used to work on a text editor based on ProseMirror and that's the only time I've written done something that resembles this 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover state for the second button is assigned the same absolute X and Y positioning values as the first button so it's appearing on top of the first button during its hover state. There's no need to restate an element's X and Y positioning on hover or active pseudo classes. The element will retain its already assigned positioning.